# Priority Queue with a complex enum?

Tags: java, enums, comparator

I am writing an Agent in Java that receives requests for its services from various other objects in the program.  The restriction is that only one process can be done at once, which means that a PriorityQueue is probably the best way to represent requests for its services.

Unfortunately, these processes are stored as a enum with many different states.  Is there an easy way to write a Comparator to order these states in the way I want?  That is,

```
public enum AgentProcess
{
    ACTION1, ACTION2, ACTION3, ACTION4, ACTION20
}
```

with some Comparator

```
public class ProcessComparator<Process>
{
    public int compare(Process a, Process b)
    {
        //some arbitrary ordering of the processes, e.g., ACTION3 > ACTION19 > ACTION4...
    }
}
```

I'm currently stuck with doing something like

```
public static int getValue(Process p)
{
    switch(p)
    case ACTION1:
         return 5;
    case ACTION2:
         return 29;
    case ACTION3:
         return 18;
    //etc
}
```

Is there a way I could rewrite my enum so that it is naturally ordered, without having to define weights or a switch for each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three solutions come to my mind:

1. You specify the enum constants in the order you need and use p.ordinal() in the comparator.
2. You specify ordering index as a parameter for the enum constant, e.g. ACTION1(3), ACTION2(4), ACTION3(1), and provide a constructor in the enum that stores the parameter to a field, which you use in the comparator.
3. Create a list of Processes where you add all the constants in the order you want, and then use list.indexOf in the comparator. This is slower than approach 1 or 2, but that might not be a problem depending where you are using it.

Comment: So in which direction does the compare work if I use the natural order?  That is, if they are listed in the Enum as "ACTION1, ACTION2, ACTION3" does it mean ACTION1 > ACTION2 > ACTION3 or ACTION1 < ACTION2 < ACTION3?

Comment: It depends on your comparator. return a.ordinal() - b.ordinal(); to order them as ACTION1, ACTION2, ... and b.ordinal() - a.ordinal() for reverse ordering.

Comment: The default constructor for PriorityQueue says it orders them by their Natural Order.  Is this order smallest first?  That is, in the above listing, ACTION1 goes in front of ACTION2 goes in front of ACTION3 by default?

Comment: @donnyton: Yes. The API documentation for Enum.compareTo() says "The natural order implemented by this method is the order in which the constants are declared."

Answer (score 2):

To expand on msell's answer #3 (keeping a list and using an indexOf to work out the sort order), this is trivially easy in the highly-recommended (at least by me) [Guava library](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/), using the [`Ordering`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) class:

```
private static final List<AgentProcess> PREFERRED_ORDER = ImmutableList.of(ACTION1, ACTION19, ACTION27 /* ... */);
private static final Comparator<AgentProcess> PROCESS_COMPARATOR = Ordering.explicit(PREFERRED_ORDER);
```

Very nice, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Stolen shamelessly from http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

```
public enum Planet {
    MERCURY (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6),
    VENUS   (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6),
    EARTH   (5.976e+24, 6.37814e6),
    MARS    (6.421e+23, 3.3972e6),
    JUPITER (1.9e+27,   7.1492e7),
    SATURN  (5.688e+26, 6.0268e7),
    URANUS  (8.686e+25, 2.5559e7),
    NEPTUNE (1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);
/* method declarations and more! */
```

Neat, I never thought I'd see pairs of floats attached to enums in any language. :)